# A quasi-isomorphism between the total complex of a Cartan-Eilenberg resolution and the complex per se.

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

## Problem

(Weibel's *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, **Exercise 5.7.1**) Suppose $A$ is a (not necessarily bounded below) chain complex over an abelian category $\mathcal A$ where axiom (AB4) holds, and $P\to A$ is a Cartan-Eilenberg resolution, then the augmentation $\operatorname{Tot}^\oplus(P)\to A$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

## Thoughts

I solved the problem when $\mathcal A$ is a category of modules. We only need to show that the mapping cone associated with the argumentation is exact. In general, I proved the following acyclic assembly lemma (A modification of Lemma 2.7.3 in Weibel):

> Let $C$ be a double complex over modules, and $C$ is an upper half-plane complex with exact columns such that the induced column cycle complexes $Z_p(C)_\bullet=(\ker d_p^h)_\bullet$ are also exact, then $\operatorname{Tot}^\oplus(C)$ is exact.

The proof of the acyclic assembly lemma goes through, and the exactness of $Z_p(C)$ is used in the last step.

However, since such a proof relies on element chasing, it might be illicit for an arbitrary abelian category $\mathcal A$ with assumption (AB4), and since the diagram is infinite, maybe Mitchell embedding theorem doesn't work. I wonder how to solve it generally.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: If $A$ is bounded below, there's no problem with using the embedding theorem.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, since for fixed $n$, in order to compute $H_n$ etc, we only need a finite portion.

Comment: Why don't you try to use a spectral sequence for this double complex? The canonical filtration for rows should degenerate at sheet 2, giving you exactly the isomorphisms between the homologies you're looking for.

Comment: @AndreaGagna Well, so only the condition that $H_n(P,d^h)$ is exact is used here? It is claimed in the text that AB5 should be assumed in the classical convergence theorem, though it seems to me that the construction and proof for everything is for modules, not generally for abelian categories. If you are right, I hope you can post an answer and I'll read it and accept it in weekends.

Comment: The axiom (AB4) ensures the commutativity of homology with coproducts. A more general result, from which this exercise follows as corollary, is proven in Lemma 12, Section III.7.13 of _Methods of Homological Algebra_ by S. Gelfand and Y. Manin.

Comment: @AndreaGagna I just skimmed G&M and found that they assume that the double complex is bounded. It's a different story. But the spectral sequence with filtration by rows works (assuming AB5), since it's upper half-plane therefore the spectral sequence converges to $\operatorname{Tot}^\oplus$.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Why are the rows exact? This is just not true. The resolution is constructed so that the columns are exact